# ¿Cómo hacer que un ciclo for corra mas rapido en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5

Hice un codigo que intenta romper un hash md5 generando caracteres hasta que estos caracteres generen un hash md5 igual.

El problema es que es muy lento. Le toma como tres a cuatro minutos obtener una contraseña de 4 caracteres mientras que John the Ripper la rompe en un solo minuto o dos; sin importar la potencia o el número de núcleos del CPU, corre a la misma velocidad (Alrededor de 7.787,43 intentos por segundo). Yo revise y corre en todos los núcleos

¿Hay una manera de hacer que corra más rápido? Porque estoy seguro que ésto puede ser más eficiente

Este es el código

```
def cracking(): #The md5 cracker
    hashed_password = textBox.get() #Grabs the tk.Entry with the password
    print(hashed_password)
    sleep(2)
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation
    attempts = 0
    done = 0
    #chars gets all the ascii values, attempts is the number of attempts, done is when it is found

    for password_length in range(1, 36): #This will attempt from a single set to 36 sets
        for guess in itertools.product(chars, repeat=password_length): 
            attempts += 1 #Adds one attempt to 0
            guess = ''.join(guess) #Adds one character if the last possible char is done
            hashing_guess = hashlib.md5(guess.encode()) #Turns the guess to md5
            hashed_guess = hashing_guess.hexdigest() #Turns the md5 into a string

            if hashed_guess == hashed_password: #Compares it and if it is found, it is done
                formated_result = format(attempts, ",") #Formarts the attempts to make them legible
                congrats = "Your hash: " + hashed_password + " took this many guesses to crack: " + formated_result + ". Your password is: " + guess
                messagebox.showinfo(message=congrats, title="Password found")
                done = 1

            print(guess, hashed_guess, attempts)

            if(done==1): #If it is done, clears everything and breaks the for loop
                if nombre_os == "posix":
                    system('clear')
                else:
                    system('cls')
                break
```

Comment: 1. No duermas al prorama (si usas alguna interfaz gráfica entonces se quedará congelada durante ese tiempo ) 2. Evita hacer demasiadas llamadas a funciones 3. (poco relevante) te puedes ahorrar 1 `if`

Comment: Incluso sin ese sleep, corre a la misma velocidad

Comment: Saca la llamada a print() del bucle, o reduce las veces que lo llamas (aunque sea con más texto cada vez). Cada llamada a print() consume una gran cantidad de tiempo en comparación con otras instrucciones.

Comment: Al margen de todas las optimizaciones que puedes hacer en python (que son varias), la velocidad **nunca** será comparable a la de John de Ripper que está escrito en C, y se ejecuta directamente en código máquina nativo en vez de ser ejecutado por un intérprete. Además Python tiene un famoso problema con los hilos. Aunque hicieras una implementación multithread, su rendimiento sería igual (o peor) que una implementación en un solo thread

Comment: No hay nada repetido en el algoritmo; nada que se haga dos veces o una password que se examine más de una vez. No se ven otras mejoras aparte de eliminar instrucciones "inútiles", como el `print`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La función print ralentiza MUCHISIMO a los programas. Mi consejo es que trates de usarla lo menos posible. Y si no los usas mejor aun.

De hecho, hice dos funciones de prueba que se detienen a los 10000 intentos. No revisa ninguna contraseña, solo itera sobre las posibles combinaciones, suma 1 a la variable attemps y une con cadena vacia todos los items de guess.

Sin embargo son una demostración de lo mucho que muchos prints pueden demorar un programa:

```
from tkinter import messagebox
from timeit import timeit
import string
import itertools
import os

hashed_password = "contraseña" #Grabs the tk.Entry with the password

def cracking_with_print(): #The md5 cracker
    print(hashed_password)
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation
    attempts = 0
    done = 0
    #chars gets all the ascii values, attempts is the number of attempts, done is when it is found

    for password_length in range(1, 36): #This will attempt from a single set to 36 sets
        for guess in itertools.product(chars, repeat=password_length): 
            attempts += 1 #Adds one attempt to 0
            guess = ''.join(guess) #Adds one character if the last possible char is done

            print(guess, attempts)

            if(done==1): #If it is done, clears everything and breaks the for loop
                if nombre_os == "posix":
                    system('clear')
                else:
                    system('cls')
                break

            if(attempts == 10000):
                return

def cracking_without_print(): #The md5 cracker
    print(hashed_password)
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + string.punctuation
    attempts = 0
    done = 0
    #chars gets all the ascii values, attempts is the number of attempts, done is when it is found

    for password_length in range(1, 36): #This will attempt from a single set to 36 sets
        for guess in itertools.product(chars, repeat=password_length): 
            attempts += 1 #Adds one attempt to 0
            guess = ''.join(guess) #Adds one character if the last possible char is done

            if(done==1): #If it is done, clears everything and breaks the for loop
                if nombre_os == "posix":
                    system('clear')
                else:
                    system('cls')
                break

            if(attempts == 10000):
                return

tiempo1 = timeit(cracking_with_print, number=1)
tiempo2 = timeit(cracking_without_print, number=1)

os.system("cls")
print("con print", tiempo1)
print("SIN print", tiempo2)
os.system("pause")
```

Esto produce:

```
con print 1.6287000999999999
SIN print 0.0013448999999998712
```

Observa como la función con print se demoró casi 2 segundos, mientras que la de sin print solo le tomo poco mas de una milesima de segundo. La diferencia es muy grande, hasta a mi me sorprendió.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora hace 908.043,20 intentos por segundo

Comment: los `print()` solo deben ser usados para ver cosas en la etapa de desarrollo. A esto me refería a "no hacer demasidas llamadas a funciones" :D