# IP Range scanner con python

Tags: python, login, python-requests, ip

estoy trabado en un script que realice de un IP SCANN con puerto fijo. Digamos, yo ingreso una IP, por ejemplo 162.86.0.5 y el SCRIPT hace peticiones hasta el numero 162.86.255.255. En casa peticion hace un loguin de cada IP, si la IP esta en linea. El script funciona, pero es muy lento, va de 1 IP a 1... digamos que un proceso de 500 IPs me demora horas, y me gustaria poder hacer, por ejemplo, que scanee con loguin 20 IP por peticion. Como todas las IP son diferentes, no hay problema de Banneo, ya que solo se realice una vez por peticion. Pero no se como hacer para que se hagan muchas peticiones en cada intento.
Aqui el codigo.

```
    import requests
    import colorama
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
    colorama.init(autoreset=True)
    
    
    
    ip = input("Ingrese ip a escanear: ")
    puerto = input("Ingrese puerto: ")
    
    parte = ip.split(".")
    a = "."
    parts_0 = parte[0]
    parts_1 = parte[1]
    parts_2 = int(parte[2])
    parts_3 = int(parte[3])
    
    payload = {
        'username': 'username',
        'password': 'password',
        "login_button": 'Login'
    }
    
    
    with open(r"D:\prueba.txt", "w"):
        for n in range(parts_2, 255):
            for x in range(parts_3,255):
                enlace = "http://" + parte[0] + a + parte[1] + a + str(n) + a + str(x) + ":" + puerto + '/login.php'
                print(enlace)
                try:
                    with requests.Session() as s:
                        peticion = s.get(enlace)
                        if peticion.status_code == 200:
                            r = s.post(enlace, data=payload)
                            with open(r"D:\prueba.txt", "a+",
                                      encoding="utf8") as panel:
                                with print_look:
                                    print(enlace + Fore.GREEN + " Respuesta:" + Fore.GREEN + "EXITO")
                                    panel.write(str(enlace))
                                    panel.write("\n")
    
                except:
                    pass
```

Como dije, el SCRIPT funciona pero necesito hacer que sea mas rapido, digamos que haga 20 o 30 peticiones por scanneo.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer esta respuesta que di hace tiempo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488708/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-que-un-ciclo-for-corra-mas-rapido-en-python/488717#488717 Estoy seguro de que aplicar lo que digo ahí hará de tu código más rapido.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1- Elimina tantos prints como puedas.

Como dije hace un mes en [una respuesta a otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488708/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-que-un-ciclo-for-corra-mas-rapido-en-python/488717#488717) la función print ralentiza muchísimo a los programas.

Está bueno informar a los usuarios, pero si lo más importante es la velocidad, entonces hay que informar menos. Si es posible ni siquiera informar.

En conclusión, quita tantos prints como puedas de tu código.

#### 2-no abras el txt varias veces.

Si tienes el archivo prueba.txt ya abierto, para que vas a reabrirlo dentro de los bucles for? Directamente abrelo una vez (como haces al principio) y escribe en el. No es necesario volver a abrirlo para poder escribir.

---

Puede que haya otras optimizaciones importantes que hacer que tengan que ver con el modulo requests, pero yo no se nada sobre eso. Si otra respuesta suma más optimizaciones, te recomiendo darle atención.

Tu código aplicando los puntos antes mencionados quedaría así:

```
import requests
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
colorama.init(autoreset=True)



ip = input("Ingrese ip a escanear: ")
puerto = input("Ingrese puerto: ")

parte = ip.split(".")
a = "."
parts_0 = parte[0]
parts_1 = parte[1]
parts_2 = int(parte[2])
parts_3 = int(parte[3])

payload = {
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    "login_button": 'Login'
}


with open(r"D:\prueba.txt", "w") as panel:
    for n in range(parts_2, 255):
        for x in range(parts_3,255):
            enlace = "http://" + parte[0] + a + parte[1] + a + str(n) + a + str(x) + ":" + puerto + '/login.php'
            try:
                with requests.Session() as s:
                    peticion = s.get(enlace)
                    if peticion.status_code == 200:
                        r = s.post(enlace, data=payload)

                        with print_look:
                            panel.write(str(enlace))
                            panel.write("\n")

            except:
                pass
```

Comment: Me parece de mucha ayuda tu comentario, no sabia lo de los print, y mucno menos lo de los txt.. los pondre aprueba, de igual manera, aguardo una ayuda sobre threading, hilos, ya que vi muchas info sobre ese tema, pero no se como implementarlo en este codigo. Pero como dije, tu comentario vale muchisimo. Gracias

Comment: De nada, me alegro de contribuir c: