# Como Optimizar proceso de actualizar base de datos en FastApi

Tags: python, base-de-datos, api

actualmente tengo un codigo en un framework de FastApi que consulta servicios para actualizar e insertar datos en una cierta database, leyendo un csv file. Mi problema reside en que el programa toma mucho tiempo en analizar, recopilar y finalmente actualizar o insertar datos (al rededor de mas de 1 hora), aproximadamente 8500 filas del csv file.

¿Hay una mejor manera de hacerlo mas rapido?, necesito ayuda por favor.

Adjunto codigo:

```
                                if row[0] == 'A':
                                    count_exist_A += 1

                                    portabilidad_msisdn = int(
                                        (row[1]+row[2]))

                                    

                                    if portabilidad_msisdn not in dict_msisdn['msisdn']:
                                        print(
                                            "ID NO EXISTE DENTRO DE SERVICIO !!")

                                        url = os.getenv(
                                            'URL_EXT', '{root}')
                                        headers = {'X-Api-Auth': os.getenv(
                                            'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXT', '{token}'), 'content-type': 'application/json'}
                                        payload = {
                                            "msisdn": portabilidad_msisdn,
                                            "operator_id": final_id
                                        }
                                        insert_msisdn = requests.post(
                                            f"{url}/routing/ported_number", data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json()
                                        print(
                                            "DATOS INGRESADOS CORRECTAMENTE !", insert_msisdn)

                                        count_exist_A_not_msisdn += 1

                                    
                                    else:
                                        print(
                                            "ID EXISTE DENTRO DE SERVICIO !!")

                                        url = os.getenv(
                                            'URL_EXT', '{root}')
                                        headers = {'X-Api-Auth': os.getenv(
                                            'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXT', '{token}'), 'content-type': 'application/json'}
                                        payload = {
                                            "msisdn": portabilidad_msisdn,
                                            "operator_id": final_id
                                        }
                                        update_msisdn = requests.put(
                                            f"{url}/routing/ported_number", data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers).json()
                                        print(
                                            "DATOS ACTUALIZADOS CORRECTAMENTE !", update_msisdn)

                                        count_exist_duplicate_msisdn += 1
```

Comment: Quita todos los `print`

Comment: La prescencia de los print son, probablemente, la razón principal por la que el proceso tarda tanto. Mira esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488708/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-que-un-ciclo-for-corra-mas-rapido-en-python/488717#488717 Mejor tomar el consejo de Christian no?