# Cree un programa que me compara dos numeros (los lee de archivo txt) ;en Python ; pero es lento

Tags: python

Cree un programa que me compara dos numeros (los lee de archivo txt) en Python ;pero es lento.Se puede cambiar el ciclo for por el ciclo while ???

```
y=int(input("introduce numero A:"))
j=int(input("introduce numero B:"))

for i in range(1,1200000 ):
    file = open("XXpi.txt")        
    nlinea = [y+i]                             
  
    for pos, l_num in enumerate(file):          
            if pos in nlinea:        
                                          
                    a=(l_num[:3])
                    b=(l_num[6:])
    file = open("XXpi.txt")               
    nlinea = [i+j]                         
  
    for pos, l_num in enumerate(file):    
                if pos in nlinea:                    
                    d=(l_num[:3])
                    e=(l_num[6:])              
                    
                    if (a,b)==(d,e):
                        print(nlinea)
```

[El archivo txt es de la forma que aparece en la imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6KkW.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6KkW.jpg)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Si abres el archivo dos veces en cada iteración del bucle for, claro que va a ser lento. De cualquier modo, esta pregunta se parece mucho a esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537496/como-hacer-mas-rapido-este-codigo-python. Por que no aplicaste las respuestas que te dimos?

Comment: Aplique todas las correcciones que ustedes me recomendaron .. con todo eso se demora mas de 2 horas en encontrar la solucion .. lo intetnte con la funcion while pero no me funciono (mi nivel de programacion es bajo),,.. graciass

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como hacer mas rapido este codigo Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537496/como-hacer-mas-rapido-este-codigo-python)