# El texto no se junta como debería y encima se repiten textos individuales

Tags: python

Quiero crear un programa que me junte el texto de dos archivos. El problema con este código es que el texto no se junta como debería y encima se repiten textos individuales.

```
f = open("ma.txt", "r")
m=open("mini.txt","r")

c=open("comb.txt","r")
for f in m:
    global linea
    global flinia
    global clinia
    f = open("ma.txt", "r")
    linea =  f.readline()
    flinia = m.readline()
    clinia = c.readline()
    if linea != clinia:
        a=open("comb.txt","a")
        print(linea+flinia)
        a.write(linea+flinia)
    else:
        print("Esto ya ha passado")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo después de que se ejecute el script

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No publiques imagenes; coloca el texto como tal. Explica cual es el criterio para "unir texto"

Comment: Esa variable f se sobrescribe es un fichero y un str...pinta muy mal

Comment: haber lo que quieres hacer es que dos textos iguales pero que el final sea distinto se unan o que podrias explicarmelo

Comment: Quiero que el texto en los dos archivos se unan.Y el resultado escribirlo en otro archivo.

Comment: se unan en una linea por linea o en dos lineas por linea(que es lo que haces ahora)...

Comment: cuando  lees una linea también lees el salto de linea y si las '+' son dos lineas así no funciona bien lo que intentas

Comment: Importante poner un pequeño ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer

Comment: siempre estas leyendo la misma linea del fichero ma.txt...tienes que sacarlo del bucle

Comment: Que sea más+el
Pues quiero que el resultado sea masel

Comment: Para que se te concatenen en una sola linea deberias hacer :a.write(linea[:-1]+flinia)

Comment: Mencionas que quieres unir dos archivos, pero no está claro cuáles ¿son "mini.txt" y "ma.txt"? ¿Y el resultado lo quieres en "comb.txt"? ¿Por qué abres entonces "comb.txt" para lectura al inicio, y más adelante lo abres otra vez en modo append? ¿Por qué comparas `if linea !=clinea`? Hay muchas lagunas en tu enunciado. Intenta ser más claro, pon un ejemplo de los dos ficheros de entrada y de la salida que deseas.

Comment: Entiendo que comb.txt sirve para controlar que  líneas se han tratado en las ultimas ejecuciones para no volverlas a tratar ¿confirmas?

Comment: mini.txt 1\n2\n3 ma.txt a\nb\nc => 1a\n2b\n3c en comb.txt donde \n es salto de líneas en los ficheros

Comment: Si para tener los resultados y no tener que repetir los resultados

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es básicamente:

- Leer una línea de "mini.txt"
- Leer otra línea de "ma.txt"
- Juntar ambas en una sola y escribir el resultado en "comb.txt"
- Repetir lo anterior mientras haya líneas en "mini.txt" o en "ma.txt"

El último punto es importante, pues ¿tienen ambos ficheros el mismo número de líneas? De no ser así ¿qué hacer cuando uno de los dos se termine pero no el otro? Doy por hecho que si uno se termina, se continúa con el otro como si el que se terminó estuviera lleno de "líneas en blanco". Sólo cuando ambos se terminan, el bucle finaliza.

Esto puede hacerse de forma mucho más sencilla y limpia de lo que estabas haciendo, con un par de trucos:

1. Usar la sentencia `with` para abrir los ficheros y obtener sus variables manejadoras. Esta sentencia es muy recomendable mientras se trabaja con ficheros porque cuando el bloque `with` termina, los ficheros son automáticamente cerrados sin necesidad de usar el método `.close()`
2. Abrir los ficheros de entrada en modo lectura y el de salida en modo escritura. No veo por qué abrirlo en modo "append" como tú hacías. De este modo tampoco hay que andar mirando si las líneas procesadas estaban ya en la salida o no (cosa que de todas formas estabas haciendo mal).
3. Usar `rstrip()` sobre las líneas leidas, para quitarles el \n que llevan al final ya que de otro modo ese \n formaría parte de lo que escribes al fichero de salida, y por tanto te salen el líneas separadas.
4. Usar la condición de que ambas líneas leidas tengan algo como condición del bucle. Esto es fácil de expresar en python:  `while linea_1 and linea_2`.

En definitiva, el código sería:

```py
with open("mini.txt","r") as mini, open("ma.txt","r") as ma, open("comb.txt","w") as comb:
    linea_1 = linea_2 = True
    while linea_1 and linea_2:
        linea_1 = mini.readline()
        linea_2 = ma.readline()
        resultado = linea_1.rstrip() + linea_2.rstrip() + "\n"
        comb.write(resultado)
```

#### Demo

Contenido de `mini.txt`:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Contenido de `ma.txt`

```
a
b
c
d
```

Resultado en `comb.txt`

```
1a
2b
3c
4d
5
```

Si no entendí correctamente el problema acláramelo en comentarios.

## Otra forma más pythónica

También puedes aprovecharte del hecho de que en python un fichero abierto (es decir, las variables `mini` y `ma`) son iterables. Si haces un bucle `for` sobre un fichero abierto, cada iteración te devuelve una línea, lo que evita tener que escribir explícitamente el `.readline()`.

Además, la función `zip()` permite iterar por dos (o más) iterables en paralelo, devolviendo en cada iteración un par, con los valores extraidos de cada uno de ellos.

Con ese par de trucos podría reescribirse el código así:

```py
with open("mini.txt","r") as mini, open("ma.txt","r") as ma, open("comb.txt","w") as comb:
    for linea_1, linea_2 in zip(mini, ma):
        resultado = linea_1.rstrip() + linea_2.rstrip() + "\n"
        comb.write(resultado)
```

**Nota**. La función `zip()` se detiene cuando uno de los dos iterables que le pasas se termine. Es decir, en este caso el bucle se abandona cuando finalice el fichero más corto, en vez de seguir como en la implementación anterior hasta que se agote el más largo. Si quisieras que se comporte como el anterior, deberías usar `zip_longest(mini, ma, fillvalue="")` en vez de `zip()`, pero para poder usar éste debes añadir un `from itertools import zip_longest` al inicio.

Comment: Me gusto la forma de manejar los ficheros, estaría bueno que agregarás la funcionalidad que si ya se han procesados los ficheros salga el mensaje...para que quede de 10

Comment: @Francisco La verdad que no entiendo a qué te refieres. ¿Qué mensaje quieres que salga si ya se han procesado los ficheros? ¿Y cómo se podría saber si ya se han procesado? ¿Quieres decir si se detecta que existe "combi.txt"? Pero aún así, los ficheros de entrada podrían haber cambiado y podríamos querer volver a generar el "combi.txt" de todas formas.

Comment: el mensaje "Esto ya ha passado"

Comment: el comb.txt no hay que borrarlo cada vez que se ejecute el proceso...porque ahí hay información valiosa

Comment: para poder enviar el famoso mensaje e indicar que nuevas líneas que se han introducido desde la ultima ejecución

Comment: @Francisco ¿Cómo sabes eso? No eres el autor de la pregunta original, no? ¿O sí? Yo entendí que en el código original usaba el modo "append" porque no sabía hacerlo en modo "write", no porque hubiera que hacerlo así. De hecho el OP ha aceptado la respuesta... Por otro lado, si quieres conservar el fichero y usar el modo "append" ¿qué habría que añadir? ¿Sólo líneas que no estuvieran ya en el fichero? ¿Y si "mini.txt" contiene 1, 2, 1, 2, mientras "ma.txt" contiene a, b, a, b. Entonces la salida debería contener 1a, 2b, 1a, 2b o bien debería omitir 1a y 2b la segunda vez por estar ya presentes?

Comment: Se lo pregunte en los comentarios...junto con el análisis del código que el realizo...puedo estar equivocado, pero por lógica y experiencia.

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo tu lógica de programa , cambiando el orden algunas sentencias y un poco de mi conocimiento:

```
m=open("mini.txt","r")
c=open("comb.txt","r")
f = open("ma.txt", "r")
for guia in m:
    global linea
    global flinia
    global clinia

    linea =  f.readline()
    flinia = guia
    clinia = c.readline()
    if linea[:-1] != clinia[:len(linea)-1]:
        a=open("comb.txt","a")
        print(linea[:-1]+flinia[:-1])
        a.write(linea[:-1]+flinia)
        a.close()
    else:
        print("Esto ya ha passado")
```

*Nota
*Lo he echo así para que lo entienda el OP*.

**En la segunda y posteriores ejecuciones no debería añadir mas líneas a comb si no se han añadido mas filas al archivo guía que es mini.txt.**
Y mostrar las nuevas líneas añadidas a *'mini'* (+*'ma'*) que no estaban en *'comb'*

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo en el uso de print en exceso. Eso es por que [print ralentiza muchisimo a los programas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/488717/158880)

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo .Supongo que se podrá redirigir a un fichero.

Comment: Podria hacerse una especie de log, si. Habria que ver que tanto afectaría a la velocidad del programa.

Comment: Estos tipos programas se hacen para trabajar en pipeline con otros