# Carga eficiente de datos a mySQL python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde tienen la información en 24 archivos csv lo que estoy haciendo es leer esos archivos en distintos df de pandas y los almaceno en un diccionario.

```
archivos={año:df_anio}
```

Antes de cargar la información debo modificar algunos valores de las columnas y descartar los registros que cumplan ciertas condiciones; para hacer esto estoy creando un df auxiliar donde almaceno los nombres correctos de columnas y la información verificada. Luego este df auxiliar ya lo subo a mySQL usando este código:

```
# Clase de conexión 
class BaseDatos:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            host = json.load(open('credenciales.json'))['host_MySQL']
            user = json.load(open('credenciales.json'))['user_MySQL']
            passwd = json.load(open('credenciales.json'))['contraseña_MySQL']
            port= json.load(open('credenciales.json'))['port']
            database = 'data_1997_2021'
            self.conn = pymysql.connect(
                host = host,
                user = user,
                passwd = passwd,
                database = database
            )
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            self.engine = ce(f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{passwd}@{host}:{port}/{database}", connect_args={'connect_timeout': 10}, echo=False)
        except:
            print('Error al conectarse a la base de datos')

# código de carga
db=BaseDatos()
columnas=['id_registro',...,'clasificacion']
for anio in archivos:
    df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columnas)
    # Carga de datos a df 
    df.to_sql('principal', con=db.engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000, method='multi')
```

En total estoy trabajando cerca de 9 millones de registros esparcidos no uniformemente en los archivos y 41 atributos. En las pruebas que he hecho en cargar los datos de los primeros 8 archivos se tarda casi 1 hora

- Como puedo realizar de forma eficiente la carga de datos?
- Existen buenas practicas que sean aplicables a lo que estoy haciendo

Edit:

```
# Clase de conexión 
class BaseDatos:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            host = json.load(open('credenciales.json'))['host_MySQL']
            user = json.load(open('credenciales.json'))['user_MySQL']
            passwd = json.load(open('credenciales.json'))['contraseña_MySQL']
            port= json.load(open('credenciales.json'))['port']
            database = 'data_1997_2021'
            self.conn = pymysql.connect(
                host = host,
                user = user,
                passwd = passwd,
                database = database
            )
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            self.engine = ce(f"mysql+pymysql://{user}:{passwd}@{host}:{port}/{database}", connect_args={'connect_timeout': 10}, echo=False)
        except:
            print('Error al conectarse a la base de datos')

# carga de datos
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
db=BaseDatos()
ruta='data/conjunto_de_datos/atus_anual_anio.csv'
# datos de remplazo
dias_semana={'No especificado':'0','Lunes':'1','Martes':'2','Miércoles':'3','Jueves':'4','Viernes':'5','Sábado':'6','Domingo':'7', 'Miercoles':'3', 'Sabado':'6', 'lunes':'1', 'martes':'2', 'miércoles':'3', 'jueves':'4', 'viernes':'5', 'sábado':'6', 'domingo':'7', 'miercoles':'3', 'sabado':'6'}
columnas_old=['ANIO','MES','DIASEMANA','ID_DIA','ID_HORA','ID_MINUTO','TIPACCID','CLASACC','AUTOMOVIL','CAMPASAJ','MICROBUS','PASCAMION','OMNIBUS','TRANVIA','CAMIONETA','CAMION','TRACTOR','FERROCARRI','MOTOCICLET','BICICLETA','OTROVEHIC','CAUSAACCI','CAPAROD','SEXO','ALIENTO','CINTURON','ID_EDAD','CONDMUERTO','CONDHERIDO','PASAMUERTO','PASAHERIDO','PEATMUERTO','PEATHERIDO','CICLMUERTO','CICLHERIDO','OTROMUERTO','OTROHERIDO','NEMUERTO','NEHERIDO']
columnas=['anio','mes','dia_semana', 'dia', 'hora', 'minuto','tipo_accidente','calsificacion_accidente','automovil','camioneta','microbus','camion','omnibus','tranvia','camioneta_carga','camion_carga','tractor','ferrocarril','motocicleta','bicicleta','otro','causa_accidente','pavimento','sexo','aliento_alcohol','cinturon_seguridad','edad','condutores_muertos','conductores_herdos','pasajeros_muertos','pasajeros_heridos','peatones_muertos','peatones_heridos','ciclistas_muertos','ciclistas_heridos','otros_muertos','otros_heridos','muertos_no_identificados','heridos_no_identificados']
for file in range(1997,2022):
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(ruta.replace('anio', str(file)), index_col=False, chunksize=10000):
        # Filtro de datos
        chunk = chunk[chunk['DIASEMANA']!='Certificado cero']
        chunk = chunk[chunk['TIPACCID']!='Certificado cero']
        chunk = chunk[chunk['CAUSAACCI']!='Certificado cero']
        chunk = chunk[chunk['CAPAROD']!='Certificado cero']
        chunk = chunk[chunk['SEXO']!='Certificado cero']
        chunk = chunk[chunk['ALIENTO']!='Certificado cero']
        chunk = chunk[chunk['CINTURON']!='Certificado cero']
        chunk = chunk[chunk['CLASACC']!='Certificado cero']
        # Correccion de datos
        chunk['ALIENTO'] = chunk['ALIENTO'].replace('No especificado', 'Se ignora')
        chunk['CINTURON'] = chunk['CINTURON'].replace('No especificado', 'Se ignora')
        # Preparacion dataframe
        chunk.insert(0, 'id_municipio', (chunk['ID_ENTIDAD'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + chunk['ID_MUNICIPIO'].astype(str).str.zfill(3)).to_list())
        chunk['MES']=chunk['MES'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
        chunk['DIASEMANA']=chunk['DIASEMANA'].map(dias_semana)
        col=chunk.pop('DIASEMANA')
        chunk.insert(3, col.name, col)
        chunk['ID_DIA']=chunk['ID_DIA'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
        col=chunk.pop('ID_DIA')
        chunk.insert(4, col.name, col)
        chunk['ID_HORA']=chunk['ID_HORA'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
        chunk['ID_MINUTO']=chunk['ID_MINUTO'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
        chunk.insert(8,'zona', np.where(chunk['URBANA']!='Sin accidente en esta zona', chunk['URBANA'], chunk['SUBURBANA']))
        chunk['CAPAROD']=np.where(chunk['CAPAROD']=='Pavimentada', 1,0)
        col=chunk.pop('CLASACC')
        chunk.insert(9, col.name, col)
        # eliminar columnas innecesarias
        chunk.drop(columns=['COBERTURA','ESTATUS','ID_ENTIDAD', 'ID_MUNICIPIO','URBANA', 'SUBURBANA'], inplace=True)
        # correccion nombre columnas
        chunk.rename(columns=dict(zip(columnas_old, columnas)), inplace=True)
        chunk.to_sql('principal', con=db.engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=5000, method='multi')
```

Archivo ejemplo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1etdBoEI_Nc9DPw2pKka2PBn0rRZXE_AN/view?usp=share_link

El archivo que comparto es el mas pesado de los que voy a trabajar, el resto de archivos tiene un peso promedio de 95 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Un código

La forma más eficiente que se me ocurre es la siguiente:

```
"""
IMPORTANTE: ESTE CÓDIGO GENERA 10 ARCHIVOS EN EL DIRECTORIO DE TRABAJO (QUE 
SUELE SER EL DEL PROGRAMA).
"""

import pandas as pd
import random
import sqlite3

# Genero 10 csv con un millon de registros cada uno
for i in range(10):
    with open(f"archivo{i}.csv", "w") as file:
        for i in range(1_000_000):
            file.write("{i},{i},{i}\n")

# Me conecto a una base de datos sqlite para hacer pruebas
cnx = sqlite3.connect("prueba.db")

# Recorremos cada número de archivo
for file in range(10):
    print(file, "/", 10)

    # Recorremos cada chunk del csv
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(f"archivo{file}.csv", header=None, chunksize=10000):
        # Eliminamos con un criterio aleatorio registros de dicho chunk
        chunk = chunk[chunk[0].apply(lambda value:bool(random.randrange(2)))]

        # Lo enviamos a sql.
        chunk.to_sql("tabla", con=cnx, if_exists="append")
```

He evitado el uso de bucles for lo más posible para ser rapido y usé un sistema de chunks para evitar llenar la memoria (si no, tus csvs podrían ser tan grandes que cargarlos en un solo df podría llenar la memoria).

El código asume que el filtro que deseas aplicar a los registros no depende de otros registros.

A mi, el proceso me tardó solo un minuto a pesar de los 10 millones de registros.

#### Algunos consejos de optimización

Tengo la supocición que hayas intentado algo muy similar a mi (sin la optimización de memoria) y que la demora se debe a alguna de las cosas que mencionaré aquí:

- *[los prints ralentizan mucho al código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/488717/158880)*, es mejor usarlos lo menos posible. Quizá los usas para mostrar el progreso de tu programa y terminaron haciendote esperar una hora.
- *No uses bucles for para trabajar con Pandas siempre que sea posible.* Python es lento, por eso cuando un módulo implementa cosas en C, el lenguaje sobre el que corre Python que es más rapido, hay que aprovechar si deseas velocidad. Las funciones de Pandas están, en su mayoría, escritas en C. Eso las hace más rapidas y mejores que un bucle for.
- *Cuida la memoria*. No se si lo sabías, y esta es una de las cosas que no me gusta mucho de pandas, y es que el df está completamente cargado en memoria. Incluso si lees un csv desde un archivo, pandas lee todo el archivo en un df y queda totalmente cargado en memoria. Si trabajás con grandes cantidades de datos y podés trabajar con ellos de a chunks, te recomiendo hacerlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya implemente el código que propones pero se volvió mas lento el proceso. Para poder implementar tu propuesta tuve que hacer estos cambios para adaptar los filtros que estoy usando:
* drop de 6 columnas
* pop de 3 columnas
* insert 5 columnas
* rename de 39 columnas
Alguna de estas modificaciones podrían ser las responsables de que el desempeño de esta nueva versión sea peor que la anterior?

Comment: Todo suma, pero no pareciera relevante. Si me das una muestra de tu csv (no tienen que ser datos reales) y el código nuevo editando la pregunta, podría intentar hacer pruebas a ver que está pasando. Recuerda notificarme cuando me des esa info. Por cierto, leiste los consejos de optimisación? Para mi es por prints.

Comment: Ya realice las modificaciones que me pides a la pregunta.
Ya elimine los prints después de leer los consejos de optimización. 
Lo que se me ocurre que este haciendo ineficiente la carga de datos es el tamaño de los chunks, en el for que tu propones use el mismo parámetro que tu de 10,000 y aparte al hacer la carga a sql estoy haciendo por chunks de 5,000 los archivos tienen minimo 240,000 registros. 
Sabes donde puedo leer mas sobre como decidir el tamaño de chunks?

Comment: Más allá de algunos consejos que te daría pero no vienen al problema, escribí un código parecido al tuyo y usé el archivo de muestra y me tardó 12 segundos. Tal vez sea la potencia de tu pc? Los csvs son archivos en tu computadora o los estás leyendo de internet? Sobre la desición del tamaño de los chunks, ni idea de donde podés leer, pero pinta a que es algo arbitrario (siempre y cuando no sobrecargue la memoria)

Comment: Los archivos los tengo de forma local, El cogido lo estoy ejecutando en un jupyter notebook estoy usando una macBook air 2017.
Yo creo que es mi computadora, igual muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: De nada! Suerte y perdón por no poder hacer más.